# For employee users in B2B platform hide premium features/content or show+lock them?

Tags: best-practice, b2b, sales-techniques

We are building a B2B platform for companies with relatively many employees. In the platform the regular employees can report their absence, and managers can handle their employees' absences. There are also company account admin users.

We are gonna offer a basic and a premium plans for the companies.  With premium you get quite a bit more features and access to additional content. The managers will not themselves be able to upgrade to the premium plan/features, only the company account admin.

Of course we want the companies to upgrade to the premium plan, but what we are struggling with now is two main alternatives for the managers (who can't themselves upgrade to the premium features):

1. should we hide all premium features for this user group,
2. or disable them and "describe" in some way that the company have to upgrade to the premium plan for the user to be able to use it?

Our arguments for alternative 2 would be that the managers might push for the premium plan to the company admin. But an argument for alternative 1 might be that a lot of disabled features might be annoying for the regular users (the managers) and impair the user experience and their work flow.

What's your point of view here? Any good examples?

Answer (score 0):

*Options 1 & 2:*

Yes, disabled features is annoying. And, yes, it's good marketing strategy to make the managers aware of premium features.

However there's more alternatives than to hide the features.

*Options 3,4,5...*

Find other ways to promote the features particularly to managers—newsletter, email, support docs, notifications, in-app hints... (opt-out capable of course). These can even be tailored to what standard features the managers are using, and when. If someone is using a particular standard feature that has premium upgrade, let them sleep on it then provide some sort of helpful hint, hopefully demonstrating ROI.